# Want to get linear equation from model output. Also want to get a single coefficient value for a column where multiple lables are there in the eqn

Tags: r, lm, one-hot-encoding, linear-equation, modelsummary

Note(I have used One hot encoding because my data have multiple labels for multiple columns)I have  build one linear regression model using R.From the model output I am able to get the linear equation. As my data contains multiple labels for a single column , so I am getting the linear equation for all the lables with coefficients. But I want to get a single coefficient which should be average of all the coefficient or something similar.

My Code:

```
**Linear Regression:**
#define one-hot encoding function
dummy <- dummyVars(" ~ .", data=mydata)

#perform one-hot encoding on data frame
final_df_supp <- data.frame(predict(dummy, newdata=mydata))
mymodel <- lm(y ~ ., data = mydata)

**Extract linear Equation from Linear Model**
model_equation <- function(model, ...) {
  format_args <- list(...)
  
  model_coeff <- model$coefficients
  format_args$x <- abs(model$coefficients)
  model_coeff_sign <- sign(model_coeff)
  model_coeff_prefix <- case_when(model_coeff_sign == -1 ~ " - ",
                                  model_coeff_sign == 1 ~ " + ",
                                  model_coeff_sign == 0 ~ " + ")
  model_eqn <- paste(strsplit(as.character(model$call$formula), "~")[[2]], # 'y'
                     "=",
                     paste(if_else(model_coeff[1]<0, "- ", ""),
                           do.call(format, format_args)[1],
                           paste(model_coeff_prefix[-1],
                                 do.call(format, format_args)[-1],
                                 " * ",
                                 names(model_coeff[-1]),
                                 sep = "", collapse = ""),
                           sep = ""))
  return(model_eqn)
}

library(MASS)

y = data.frame(model_equation(mymodel , digits = 3, trim = TRUE))

type here
```

**Output:**
y = 2+0.05*x1.a+0.08*x1.b+0.3*x1.c+3*y1.ab+5*y1.bc+4*y1.cd

**data:**
x1 y1
a  ab
b  bc
c  cd

**I want the output should be :**
y= 2+0.34*x1+6*y1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You may want to look at the `equatiomatic` package. https://datalorax.github.io/equatiomatic/